# Viewport on Android Tablet Device

Tags: android, viewport, tablet, meta

The viewport looks good in landscape mode, but when changing to **portrait** mode on a **Android Tablet only**... the viewport stays the same width as the landscape one, and ends up zooming in, and me having to pinch the screen for it to fill...

This is what I am using at the minute across the site...works a treat on AppleDevices

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10199495/how-to-set-viewport-so-it-is-380x800-or-800x380-depending-on-orientation

Comment: thankyou for your comment I have now fixed this with abit of JS