# How to dynamically change meta tag viewport after page load in windows phonegap application?

Tags: javascript, css, html, cordova, windows-phone-8

I want to dynamically change meta tag viewport in "index.html" in windows phonegap app on button click.

I am using

- Windows OS 8
- phonegap 3.5
- Device Nokia Lumia 1320 with windows 8 OS

I want to change below meta tag

```
<meta id="viewport" name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

to

```
<meta id="viewport" name="viewport" content="width=720">
```

I have already tried below URLs but nothing worked for windows phone.

[how to set viewport so it is 380x800 or 800x380 depending on orientation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10199495/how-to-set-viewport-so-it-is-380x800-or-800x380-depending-on-orientation/10245271#10245271)

[Setting the Viewport to Scale to Fit Both Width and Height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21419404/setting-the-viewport-to-scale-to-fit-both-width-and-height)

Here I found link where it says it is not possible to change meta tag dynamically in winodws 8 OS

http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2011/06/dynamically_cha.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to detect the device/OS and change the meta tag accordingly http://www.sitepoint.com/detect-mobile-devices-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

1st write simple function JavaScript for example I have written one function viewport()

```
<html> 
<head>
    <script>
        function viewport(){
            var msViewportStyle = document.createElement("style");

            msViewportStyle.appendChild(
                document.createTextNode(
                    "@-ms-viewport{width:auto!important;zoom:1!important;}"
                )
            );

            msViewportStyle.appendChild(
                document.createTextNode(
                    "@-ms-viewport{height:auto!important}"
                )
            );

            document.getElementsByTagName("head[0].appendChild(msViewportStyle);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="btnSubmit" onclick="viewport();">changeviewport</button>
</body>
```

more..[1]:[Can I change the viewport meta tag in mobile safari on the fly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588628/can-i-change-the-viewport-meta-tag-in-mobile-safari-on-the-fly)